# 2nd order nonlinear ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for help to solve the following $F(x,y(x),y'(x),y''(x))=0$ equation:

$$
xy''(x)-y'(x)-(x^2)y(x)y'(x)=0
$$

Very much appreciated.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://po.st/83KygQ) indicates that the general solution involves $\tanh$, though I don't see an easy way to deduce that

Comment: Yes, I used wolfram alfa and was trying to solve this for some time, but could not make it, so i am looking for help here ;)

Comment: It does according to wolfarm alpha, but I am yet to learn how to do that. Thanks for the tip, tho I thought there is some other way

Answer (score 4):

The DE has an integrating factor $1/x^2$. That is, after multiplying by $1/x$, 
we get 
$$  \dfrac{y''}{x} - \dfrac{y'}{x^2} - y y' = 0 $$
which can be written as
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{y'}{x} - \dfrac{y^2}{2}\right) = 0$$ 
Integrate this:

$$ \dfrac{y'}{x} - \dfrac{y^2}{2} = C $$
 Now this is a separable equation:

$$ \dfrac{dy}{y^2 + 2C} = \dfrac{x \; dx}{2} $$

You might want to do the three cases $C > 0$, $C < 0$, $C = 0$ separately.

EDIT: How to find the integrating factor, you ask?  Actually I used Maple, but here's how one might do it by hand.

In general it's hard to find integrating factors, but if you assume the integrating factor is a function of $x$ alone, it's not too bad. The derivative of $a(x) y' + b(x,y)$ is $a(x) y'' + a'(x) y' + b_x(x,y) + b_y(x,y) y'$.
If this is to be $\mu(x) (x y'' - y' - x^2 y y')$, we need
$a(x) = \mu(x) x$, $b_x = 0$ (so $b(x,y) = b(y)$ and $b_y(x,y) = b'(y)$) and $\mu(x) (-1 + x^2 y) = a'(x) + b'(y)$.  From the last equation $b'(y) = c y$
where $\mu(x) x^2 = c$.  That gives  us the integrating factor up to an arbitrary constant.

Of course most second order DE's won't have an integrating factor of this form, but enough do that this is a useful addition to one's bag of tricks.

Comment: Insight on how to decide that the integrating factor is 1/x^2 and how did you figured out how to integrate that, would be much appreciated

Comment: Interesting, is this a general way in finding integrating factors? Becouse I am not familiar with this method (taking a(x) and b(x,y) and playing with them around)

Comment: A lot of this sort of thing goes on in trying to solve differential equations: write down a general form and see what has to be true to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the DE;

$$-x^2 y'y+xy''-y'=0 \stackrel{\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}}{\iff} \frac{y''}{x}-\frac{y'}{x^2}-y'y=0 \stackrel{\mathrm{\int \mathrm{d}x}}{\iff}\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y^2}{2}=c \iff \frac{2y'}{2c+y^2}=x \;\;\;\stackrel{\mathrm{\int \mathrm{d}x ,} \; s=\frac{y}{\sqrt{2c}}}{\iff}\;\;\; \frac{\sqrt{2} \tan^{-1} \left (\frac{y}{\sqrt{2c}}\right )}{\sqrt{c}}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1 \iff y=\sqrt{2c} \tan \left (\frac{\sqrt{c}(x^2+c_1)}{2\sqrt{2}}\right )$$

Comment: Im new, so i dont really follow you there, sorry

Comment: Tell me what part needs more explanation, I'd be glad to help. I'm relatively new to LaTeX too, so I try to do everything in one code and that may not be that descriptive. $\int \mathrm{d}x$ means I integrated with respect to $x$, the $s=\frac{y}{\sqrt{2c}}$ is the key substitution to do the integral if it's hard for you.

Comment: Oh it just got loaded. I will investigate, thanks!

Comment: Yea, I dont really understand how you integrate the first time, I mean when you have derrivatives of y. There must be some rule i dont know yet

Comment: No rules that I know of, you have to find the antiderivative by observation there.

Comment: So basicaly you stare at it until you see the answer? This is getting more and more magical, thanks for help.

Comment: Not exactly. There are some mathematical tricks that depend heavily on experience. How would you justify dividing by $x^2$, making the right substitution and integrating when needed? That's staring untill you see the magic answer too you know.